# Laravel Ajax url not pointing to public folder

Tags: laravel, .htaccess

I am new to Laravel. I have hosted my project in server in /var/www/html/projectfolder.

the project folder have public folder which has js and css files in it.

In js files, I have written ajax call.For eg,

> ```
>     $.ajax({
>         //this part
>         url: "/some/thing/",
> ```

When I checked in browser, it is pointing to

> http://servername.com/some/thing

But I need to achieve,

> http://servername.com/projectfolder/some/thing

I have htaccess file in projectfolder as follows,

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [R]
```

I have htaccess file in projectfolder/public as follows,

```
    # Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </Ifmodule>


    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

In localhost, the same code working fine as I am running the project thru php artisan serve

But in server the path is not setting.

Please help me.

Regards,
Rekha

Answer (score 0):

do this by removing the first slash /:

```
$.ajax({
        //this part
        url: "/projectfolder/some/thing/",
```

Comment: try that lets see what happens

Comment: i added projectfolder/some/thing/

Answer (score 0):

Fast add:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') } });

var url = "{{URL::to('/')}}";
```

then use

```
url:url + '/projectfolder/some/thing/'
```